# How to check if zstd installation has support for lz4?

Tags: lz4, zstandard, zstd

I installed `ztsd` on my CentOS 7 system using `yum install zstd`. How do I check if the zstd installed on my system has support for compressing in `lz4`?

Relavant link for support of lz4 in zstd - https://github.com/valyala/gozstd/blob/master/zstd/programs/README.md#compilation-variables

Note: My system already had lz4 installed when zstd was installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zstd -vV`
or equivalent
`zstd --verbose --version`

example outcome :

```
zstd -vV
*** zstd command line interface 64-bits v1.4.4, by Yann Collet ***
*** supports: zstd, zstd legacy v0.5+, gzip, lz4, lzma, xz
```

presented in the manpage (`--version` paragraph) : `man zstd` or http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/zstd/